# Georeferencing drone image different pitch-values

Tags: python, georeferencing, aerial-photography, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am trying to georeference objects on an image. The image has been taking by a drone and I know the drones parameters.
Here is my script:

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, atan2, degrees
from PIL import Image
import json
import argparse

def get_image_dimensions(image_path):
    try:
        with Image.open(image_path) as img:
            width, height = img.size
            return width, height
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
        return None, None

def main(image_path):
    # Drone metadata
    drone_latitude = 49.801051
    drone_longitude = 9.890559
    drone_altitude = 25.781  # Relative altitude in meters
    gb_yaw = 111.2  # Global bearing (yaw) in degrees
    gb_pitch = -24.4  # Global pitch in degrees

    # Camera details
    focal_length_mm = 24.00  # Focal length in mm
    sensor_width_mm = 6.4  # Assuming 1/2" sensor size
    dzoom_ratio = 1.00  # Digital zoom ratio

    image_width, image_height = get_image_dimensions(image_path)
    if image_width is not None and image_height is not None:
        with open("detections_image.json") as f:
            detections = json.load(f)
        
        # Open KML file for writing
        with open("locations.kml", "w") as kml_file:
            kml_file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n')
            kml_file.write('<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">\n')
            kml_file.write('<Document>\n')

            for detection in detections:
                object_x = detection["object_x"]
                object_y = detection["object_y"]
                class_name = detection["class"]

                # Calculate the horizontal and vertical angles of view
                hfov = 2 * atan2(sensor_width_mm / 2, focal_length_mm)  # Horizontal field of view in radians
                vfov = hfov * (image_height / image_width)  # Vertical field of view in radians

                # Calculate the angle to the object in the image
                delta_x = (object_x - (image_width / 2)) / (image_width / 2)  # Normalized delta x from center
                delta_y = (object_y - (image_height / 2)) / (image_height / 2)  # Normalized delta y from center

                angle_to_object_x = delta_x * (degrees(hfov) / 2)  # Angle to object from center, x-axis, in degrees
                angle_to_object_y = delta_y * (degrees(vfov) / 2)  # Angle to object from center, y-axis, in degrees

                # Adjust the drone bearing based on the angle to the object
                adjusted_bearing = gb_yaw + angle_to_object_x

                # Calculate the distance to the object
                distance_to_object = drone_altitude / sin(radians(-gb_pitch + angle_to_object_y))

                # Calculate the object's GPS location
                object_gps_location = calculate_new_gps(drone_latitude, drone_longitude, distance_to_object, adjusted_bearing)

                # Write location to KML file
                kml_file.write('<Placemark>\n')
                kml_file.write(f'<name>{class_name}</name>\n')
                kml_file.write('<Point>\n')
                kml_file.write(f'<coordinates>{object_gps_location[1]},{object_gps_location[0]}</coordinates>\n')
                kml_file.write('</Point>\n')
                kml_file.write('</Placemark>\n')

            kml_file.write('</Document>\n')
            kml_file.write('</kml>\n')

        print("Locations exported to locations.kml")

def calculate_new_gps(lat, lon, distance, bearing):
    R = 6371e3  # Earth radius in meters
    bearing = radians(bearing)

    lat1 = radians(lat)
    lon1 = radians(lon)

    lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(distance / R) +
                cos(lat1) * sin(distance / R) * cos(bearing))
    lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(bearing) * sin(distance / R) * cos(lat1),
                        cos(distance / R) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2))

    new_lat = degrees(lat2)
    new_lon = degrees(lon2)

    return new_lat, new_lon

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Convert detected objects in an image to GPS locations based on drone metadata and camera details.")
    parser.add_argument("image_path", type=str, help="Path to the image file for which GPS locations will be calculated.")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.image_path)
```

The script worked well for an image with pitch value of -24.4 degress, but once I turned the gimble to a pitch-value of -15.1 degrees, took an image and edited my drones parameters in the script, the resulting georeferenced objects are about 30meters off. Why is that and how can I adjust this?
Turning my gimble slightly means, that the objects are more to the buttom of the image and I am guessing there are more distortions?